# Examples of measures which are not induced by outer measures?

Tags: analysis, measure-theory

I am required to prove that subsets of null sets are not necesarily null sets. I know that the only way this can happen is if the subset of a null set is not necesarilymeasurable. I also know that if a measure is induced by an outer measure, then all null sets are measurable; so I have to look for an example of a measure not induced by an outer measure. Would you have any tips on how to start constructing a measure not induced by an outer measure? Thank you very much.

Comment: @Caffeine Thanks for your comment. But you say that Borel sets are countable. What do you mean by this? Borel sets such as $(2, 3)$ are not countable.

Comment: there exists a $2^{\aleph_0}$ quantity of borel sets, while there are $2^{2^{\aleph_0}}$ subsets of the Cantor set

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to prove that the subsets of null sets are not necessarily null sets, you need to have a sigma-algebra and a measure on it. If you want to construct one such, there are many standard examples to keep in mind.

The simplest I can think of is the following. Take any set $X$ and the sigma-algebra $\{\emptyset, X\}.$ Define a measure $\mu$ such that $\mu(\emptyset)=0=\mu(X).$ Then, $X$ is a null set but as long as $X$ has more than one element, it has non-empty subsets that are non-measurable.

Of course, this looks like cheating. But, you can modify it slightly. For example, let $X=\{1, 2, 3\}.$ Define a sigma-algebra $\{\emptyset, \{1, 2\}, \{3\}, X\},$ and set the measure of $\mu(\emptyset)=\mu(\{1, 2\})=0.$ Set $\mu(\{3\})=1=\mu(X).$

These simple examples, I believe, are clearer and give you more hands-on regarding the things going on. But, of course, you have a standard example of Borel $\sigma$-algebra which is not complete. Proving that Borel sigma-algebra is not complete, is a delightful experience. You note that the cardinality of Borel sigma-algebra is same as the cardinality of $\mathbb{R}.$ Therefore, all subsets of the Cantor set can not be measurable. But Cantor sets being closed is measurable and has measure $0$. Notice that what it tells us is that "actually most" of the subsets of the Cantor set are non-measurable.

Coming to your key question (slightly reformulated). One standard way to construct a measure is via "outer measure." But the outer-measure construction always gives you a complete sigma-algebra. (Of course, we are greedy. We define outer-measure on the power set, then restrict it to some family where the outer measure is a measure. If so, why not restrict it to the largest family you can. That's (almost) what we do. Of course, this is not correct; but I find it helpful to think this way.) Another machinery that is used to construct measures (at least on nice topological spaces) is the Riesz-representation theorem. (As far as I remember on the top of my head) The RRT also gives you a complete measure. So, it makes sense to ask where do they (non-complete measures) come from?

Well! The two pieces of machinery which would usually give you non-complete measures are "constructing measures from pre-measure" and "product measure" (which is actually a special case of the first, but who cares?).

One can start with a small algebra (this is something probabilists do more often than analysts), and define a measure like function on the algebra which has everything (except possibly the property of continuity from below. This is a restriction coming from the algebra because an algebra need not be closed under the countable union) you want. You extend this function to a sigma-algebra (but this time, you are rather nervous, and you would stop the moment you have a measure. You do not dream of having a very big sigma-algebra). This construction usually results in a non-complete measure. When we define product measure, we do exactly the same thing, we start with the cylinder sets and define their measure. This gives us a pre-measure on the algebra generated by the cylinder sets. One particularly important example to keep in mind is that the product of 1-dimensional Lebesgue measure yields the Borel sigma-algebra on $\mathbb{R}^2,$ not the Lebesgue.

Comment: Thanks for your delightful answer!